# Does includegraphics run any faster with lower bit depth images?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, png, jpeg

My images take a long time to render (using TexStudio with pdflatex). I don't want to drop the resolution (number of pixels) of the images but can afford to drop the bit depth from 24 to 8 bit without noticing much difference.

Does \includegraphics{name.jpg} run any faster with lower bit depth images of the same size? I can't really tell, but maybe there's a minor speed improvement. And as an aside, does it tend run faster with jpg, png, bmp or tiff?

Comment: you don't  say which engine you are using but assuming pdftex then jpg is usually much quicker than png (as the former can be included as-is in pdf but png has to be converted) if you have png you can convert them first to pdf to speed things up  also of course you can use draft mode and skip including teh figures when editing

Comment: Thanks. I'm using pdflatex (as per edit). I was not aware of draft mode, this will be useful, but still want faster image rendering. Are jpeg files slower than pdf?

Comment: jpg and pdf are usually about the same, but you can reduce the filesize in any nounver of ways and test if it is just for drafting you can of course agressively reduce the resolution and just switch back the images for the final run.